# BASH copy of array

Tags: arrays, bash, variables, types

I am new to BASH.

I have string with name ARRAY, but i need set ARRAY as array, and this ARRAY as array must include parts of string from ARRAY as string separated by `\n` (new line)

This is what I have:

```
ARRAY=$'one\ntwo';
x=$ARRAY;
IFS=$'\n' read -rd '' -a y <<<"$x";
y=(${x//$'\n'/});
IFS=$'\n' y=(${x//$'\n'/ });
IFS=$'\n' y=($x);
unset ARRAY; (i try unset ARRAY)
ARRAY=$y; (this not works correctrly)
echo ${ARRAY[1]}; //result ARRAY[0]="one",ARRAY[1]=""
```

But if I try `echo ${y[1]};` //all is right y[0]="one" y[1]="two"

My problem is that I cannot set ARRAY as copy of `y` array..

Comment: Please add your desired result to your question.

Comment: ARRAY[0]="one"
ARRAY[1]="two"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're splitting the string at the newlines *is correct*:

```
array=$'one\ntwo'
IFS=$'\n' read -rd '' -a y <<<"$array"
```

Now, why do you give a different name, if eventually you want the variable `array` to contain the array? just do:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -rd '' -a array <<<"$array"
```

There are no problems if `array` appears both times here.

---

Now, if you want to *copy* an array, you'll do this (assuming the array to copy is called `y` as in your example):

```
array=( "${y[@]}" )
```

Note, that this will not preserve the sparseness of the array (but in your case, `y` is not sparse so there are no problems with this).

---

Another comment: when you do `IFS=$'\n' read -rd '' -a y <<<"$array"`, `read` will return with a return code of `1`; while this is not a problem, you may still want to make `return` happy by using:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -rd '' -a array < <(printf '%s\0' "$array")
```

---

A last comment: instead of using `read` you can use the builtin `mapfile` (bash≥4.0 only):

```
mapfile -t array <<< "$array"
```